# How far ahead does NSF recruit panelists for proposal review meetings?

Tags: peer-review, nsf

[NSF has in person meetings](https://www.nsf.gov/events/advisory.jsp) as part of the peer review of grants.  How far ahead of time are the participants recruited?

I am looking for a general rule of thumb, like three to four months, not an exact answer that might depend on the panel or the program manager.

Answer (score 12):

Looking back at my records, I have had about a month and a half between my panel invitations and the panel dates.

This timing is consistent across pre-COVID in-person panels and the remote panels and ad-hoc reviewing I have done since the pandemic started.

Answer (score 9):

A NSF program officer reached out to me for a panel informally about two and a half months before the proposed panel meeting dates.  The formal invitation (after I had confirmed, in response to the first inquiry, that I was available on the dates in question) came a couple of weeks later—about two months in advance of the panel dates.

This was all well before the pandemic, however.  I don't know how things may have changed since then.